# Remove the ToolStripMenuItem left border

Tags: c#, winforms, properties, designer, toolstrip

I have my `ToolStripMenuItem` and when I run the application, it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, there is a little white space at the `ToolStripMenuItem` left.

How can I remove it? I tried to edit every property but it still remains...

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To change appearance of menu item you should use a `ToolStripProfessionalRenderer` using a custom `ProfessionalColorTable`.

To change that color, you should override `ImageMarginGradientBegin` property of custom color table and return the color you want.

[image]

For example you can have :

```
public class CustomColorTable : ProfessionalColorTable
{
    public override Color ImageMarginGradientBegin
    {
        get { return Color.Red; }
    }
    public override Color ImageMarginGradientMiddle
    {
        get { return Color.Green; }
    }
    public override Color ImageMarginGradientEnd
    {
        get { return Color.Blue; }
    }
    public override Color ToolStripDropDownBackground
    {
        get { return Color.Yellow; }
    }

    public override Color MenuItemSelected
    {
        get { return Color.Pink; }
    }

    //You should also override other properties if you need.
    //This is just a sample code to show you the solution
}
```

And then in your form load:

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ToolStripManager.Renderer = new ToolStripProfessionalRenderer(new CustomColorTable());
}
```

Comment: It actually worked, thank you very much for the help!